# How to define an Intent inside a Lambda expression

Tags: java, android, android-intent, lambda, java-8

I'm making an app in Android Studio and I want to go from my `LoginActivity` to my `MainActivity` with an `Intent` from within an `OnCompleteListener()`.

I've tried with:

```java
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainActivity);
            finish();
        }
    }
});

//and

firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainActivity);
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

With both parameters, the app compiled properly but stopped when the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method was triggered.

Is there any other parameter I can use?

Comment: On the third line from the tail I wrote "complied" instead of  "compiled", sorry for the confusion

Comment: You can always go back and edit your OP and you don't need to add comment just to say sorry. We all make typos on a daily basis. That's part of life.

Comment: What do you mean the app stopped? Did it crash? Can you share logcat? Lambda is simply going to make your code look small and cleaner but it's not going to fix a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intent` should be created in the same way as before. The `LoginActivity.this` refers to this instance of the outer LoginActivity class where is the inner anonymous class used. It probably isn't meant to substitute the `getApplicationContext()`.

As far as you tagged the [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda), your wish is to shorten the anonymous class implementation to a lambda expression, here you go:

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(mainActivity);
             finish();
         }
    });
```

Remember, the `Intent` instantiation is not related to the lambda expression. The key part is shortening the:

```
new OnCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) { ... }
}
```

... to ...

```
task -> { ... }
```